# Como redireccionar de una menú a otro en php

Tags: php, html, css

Buenas tardes compañeros tengo un menu y quiero de este entrar a una sesión de usuarios como podría hacerlo. lo que hice fue entrar todo en una carpeta que se lla user, pero no se como redireccionarla.cuando lo hago en el menú, primero me decia que error al encontrar el archivo, luego me dice acceso denegado.

```html
 </header>
    <main>




        <div class="content-menu">

            
            <li><a href="home.php"><span class="lnr lnr-home icon1"></span><h4 class="text1">Inicio </h4></li>
            <li><a href="login.php"><span class="lnr lnr-film-play icon2"></span><h4 class="text2">usuario</h4></li>
            <li><span class="lnr lnr-store icon3"></span><h4 class="text3">Productos</h4></li>
            <li><a href="income.php"><span class="lnr lnr-picture icon4"></span><h4 class="text4">income</h4></li>
            <li><span class="lnr lnr-briefcase icon5"></span><h4 class="text5">Foro</h4></li>
            <li><span class="lnr lnr-license icon6"></span><h4 class="text6">Blog</h4></li>
            <li><span class="lnr lnr-bubble icon7"></span><h4 class="text7">Mensajes</h4></li>
            <li><span class="lnr lnr-envelope icon8"></span><h4 class="text8">Contactos</h4></li>
            <li><span class="lnr lnr-question-circle icon9"></span><h4 class="text9">Nosotros</h4></li>
```

Comment: ¿Te refieres a esto: `<li><a href="login.php"><span class="lnr lnr-film-play icon2"></span><h4 class="text2">usuario</h4></li>`? ¿Qué es lo que ocurre? ¿Da error? ¿Qué error? ¿Dirige a alguna parte? ¿A dónde? ¿En qué carpeta está el archivo que muestras en la pregunta?

Comment: esta una carpeta llamada admin, y user.php

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta. No dices siquiera qué es lo que ocurre o qué error tienes ni si el actual archivo está en `admin`, si la carpeta `user` está dentro de `admin` etc. Explica el contexto, que no estamos frente a tu pantalla para saberlo.